# Why in cpanel database size is showing 0.00MB?

Tags: php, mysql, database, cpanel

Why in cpanel database size is showing 0.00MB while when i take backup of database then it is 1.2 MB?

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/392674/1107123610-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/392674/1107123610-My-Desktop.png)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely because it's not configured properly

Answer (score 1):

I believe CPanel runs a series of tasks which update counters such as database size, rather than calculating it on-the-fly. If it's not up-to-date, either the task isn't running or isn't running often enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your download includes your "information_schema" database too, I hope you acknowledge that, however I would not seem to think it would weigh about 10 megabytes of data, so the only other issue I would see as a concern is you database is not mapped so try repairing it, or creating a new database and uploading the contents to it.

Comment: information_schema is not being dumped. It's not a real database, just a collection of views (even if they appear to be MyISAM tables)

Comment: Alright. In some instances it can be downloaded with a MySQL backup.

Answer (score 0):

edit file /var/cpanel/cpanel.config and change

> disk_usage_include_sqldbs=0

to

> disk_usage_include_sqldbs=1

Then run

```
/scripts/update_db_cache
```

It will update the MySQL database disk usage.